# Is there an easy way to determine where a part goes on an airplane?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing

In order to classify parts for export I need to determine where our parts go on the plane.  (Engine or structural/body)  Specifically looking at the canister, heat shield assy and lock support for the Boeing 767/777.

Comment: It might be easier to answer your question if you provided a bit of context.

Comment: Already how do you identify these parts. Just numbers or otherwise?

Comment: I assume you are not the manufacturer? If so, you need access to some sort of database that will give you that info, In some cases a Google search will answer the question, but in obscure instances you may not find what you want.

Comment: Export related questions are best addressed to your compliance department or person. Just saying.

Comment: Do you really trust somebody on the internet to classify your part for export for you?

Comment: I don't think he's asking anyone on the Internet to do the classification, he's asking if there is a simple mechanism to do that, and besides, if there is, it's probably a web application on the Internet.

Comment: J. Hougaard - I wanted to keep my question general on purpose.  user40476 - we have two sources of information to use, but they are not always 100% correct, and I'm trying to verify that my sources/info are/is up to date.  Juan Jimenez - We are the manufacturer in most cases.  I'm just trying to verify our data is good.  AEhere - I am the compliance department - just trying to expand my sources.  vasin1987 - I'm not asking anyone to classify anything.  To All: Thank you for your input and time.  I got the answer I was looking for (thanks Dave).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a parts catalog/diagram.

[Here is one for the 767](http://www.jmcnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Polaris-B767-IPC-Supplement-31-MAR-2014-REV-2.pdf) that shows parts and where they go. Interestingly all the pictures seem to be of the BBJ (business jet) version of the 767, the other parts should remain the same.